# Contract to Hire-pregnant

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, company-culture, hiring, new-hires

Two months ago I started a 6-month long contract-to-hire job and just noticed I am pregnant. They like me and everything works out so far. First question: When should I tell them ? My concern is that they will not hire me.I know it's illegal to not hire someone because of pregnancy but they can come up with any other excuse. How probable is my concern?

Comment: Has unfavorable behavior been noticed in this company concerning personal matters? Is the culture accepting and family like or more indifferent and independent? Where do you see yourself and your new needs/priorities in 4 months and 9 months? Can you start looking now if you fear losing this opportunity? How have your 30, 60, and 90 day reviews (or check ins) been going? Do you notice any financial or operational trends that would indicate the company would not hire you at the end of the contract?

Comment: My understanding is that the culture is family like. There are many women in this company and saw couple of them being pregnant but they are full time already.I am thinking to keep working till baby comes and take at least two-three months off afterward, then go back to work.

Comment: Do you know the company's maternal leave policy or your temp agency's?

Comment: Congratulations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would talk to them sooner rather than later - they will eventually find out about your pregnancy.

You are basically going to get one of two reactions:

1) They are negative towards the situation - you now have more time to prepare yourself for the end of the contract and figure out your next step.

2) They are positive towards the situation - you now have nothing to worry about (and saved yourself some stress). Hopefully, they will be supportive and have a variety of options/solutions available to you.

This kind of approach pretty much applies to any situation where there is potential for medium/long-term absence from or disruption to work.

edit:

Following your comment above - be sure to explain that as your plan to them when talking to your supervisor/manager/company.

It will be in their interest to hold on to you even with a break, since replacing you will require advertising the position, interviewing, selecting, and training a new person. Having you absent or part-time for a period after the birth should have a much lower impact on their business.

Comment: I would _SERIOUSLY_ consider having a backup plan before letting anyone know anything. This is not a career choice move but rather a family supporting issue. It might be wise to feel out some potential other job opportunities that are full time and direct hire if you have a family because temp work is not stable enough for most families. Not to sound cliche, but the OP is thinking for two now and that can drive a seriously big pressure and stressful load onto her plate and having financial uncertainties or woes is not helpful at all.

Comment: @B1313 - generally, I'd agree with you, but the OP has a fixed contract with 4 months left - in that situation she will be better off with early disclosure for the reasons I list - I seriously doubt concealing the pregnancy until the OP is taken as a full-time hire is possible in that time frame.

Comment: this is assuming she signed a contract...that's all. Double check everything before diving in so to speak.

Comment: "Two months ago I started a 6-month long contract-to-hire job" is right there in the question

Comment: If you think you have a better answer for the OP, feel free to write it

Comment: usually when they say contract-to-hire it doesn't mean there is an actual contract. Usually because the companies needs may change sooner than that time frame and they want the ability to be agile. I like your answer, I just would make sure to not jeopardize a current job without a Plan B. It is hard to find a job normally, but being pregnant and trying to find a job is immensely difficult.

Comment: On the matter of contract-to-hire - it would be best if the OP defined that better rather than make assumptions on her behalf. If it alters the situation, I'll update my answer to suit - but answers with lots of ifs and buts and caveats are next to useless.

Comment: As for Plan B - it's a good idea to always have a Plan B, even when things look sunny...

Comment: I agree with this, let them know now, not when they start asking you if you're off your diet. Gives both sides time to think about how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should probably start looking at other jobs right about now.

Considering that pregnancy shows at a certain point, you do not have the chance of keeping it entirely secret from them.

After you have something lined up, you should tell them. Be prepared to be fired or not hired after this.

Comment: Based on her question, I'm failing to see how or why she'd need to locate a new job? She mentions nothing about what the job is or why they would feel she need to be let go of? Will she travel a lot? Outdoors a lot? Why do you think she needs to locate another job?

Comment: @Dan Sadly, most companies consider pregnancy a liability and will try everything to get rid of pregnant or about-to-be-pregnant women. I'd consider it an exception if she was not let go at the end of the 6 month contract.